# Could you help to understand the differences, advantages and disadvantages between pipeline job vs upstream/downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for differences between creating a Jenkins pipeline vs upstream/downstream jobs.
What are the advantages and disadvantages in these two and under which circumstances to use each one of these?

I am looking for advantages, disadvantages and differences over these 2 types of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using downstream builds for grey infrastructure creation. When building application code in a trunk based branching strategy, and having a terraform repo that is more of a gitflow strategy. I am able to build the grey infra against any environment regardless of where it is in the release process. I'm also just implementing pipelines that run on EKS, so having the builds fire as part of the application build completion does not lock up resources on EC2. There are some nifty plugins for connecting downstream builds if you use artifact fingerprinting. The downstream builds show on the upstream and vice versa. [image]

It helps make the JTE pipelines easier to abstract away since it is an api call to the build. I'm also running a Jenkinsfile and multibranch pipeline from the same repo which gives the flexibility for triggering downstream, manually, or from branch events.